# Grade For Student Based on Different Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

Hi All,

I am having marks of student in Different Subjects.

Table #Maths Contain marks in maths of students named as a,b and c.
Similar for #Science and #English.

Now i want output as if student have more than 75 marks in two subject he will be given grade as 'Merit'.If he is having more than 75 in one subject and more than 60 in other then grade will be 'Pass' and if none of subject is having more than 75 and one subject is less than 50 then he will be given grade as 'Fail'?

Please Provide me the solution for the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.marks, s.marks, e.marks,
CASE WHEN (m.marks > 75 and s.marks > 75) OR (s.marks > 75 and e.marks > 75) OR (m.marks > 75 and e.marks > 75) THEN 'Pass'
     WHEN (m.marks > 75 and (s.marks > 60 OR e.marks > 60)) OR
          (s.marks > 75 and (m.marks > 60 OR e.marks > 60)) OR
          (e.marks > 75 and (s.marks > 60 OR m.marks > 60)) THEN 'Pass'
     WHEN (m.marks < 75 and s.marks < 75 and e.marks < 75 and (m.marks < 50 or e.marks < 50 or s.marks < 50)) THEN 'Fail'
     ELSE NULL END as Merit
FROM #maths m
inner join #science s
on m.ID = s.ID
inner join #English e
on m.ID = e.ID
```

Not very classy but since there are only few columns that needs to be compared, i'd approach it this way

Answer (score 1):

You can try a query like below:

- This query is definitely faster than Joins as it reduces the operation set for the case condition
- The business logic is neatly encapsulated as part of weights and top query conditions
- No Joins and therefore faster. Speed will become apparent when you start increasing student records and subject tables.

Query:

```
select 
  id, 
  name, 
  case 
       when sum(weightRank) >=32 then "Merit"
       when sum(weightRank) >=20 then "Pass"
       when sum(weightRank) <16 and  count(ALL weightRank) < count(weightRank)    
       then "Fail"
       else "N/A"
  end as grade
from
 (
    select id,name,'m' as subject,marks from #maths
        union all 
    select id,name,'m' as subject,marks from #science
        union all
    select id,name,'m' as subject,marks from #english 
) allmarks

-- allmarks get all records together, and is faster than joining all tables
-- this is also extensible as subjects and students may increase
-- and not all subjects may have marks for all students, so we will not lose data as in case of joins

    join 
        (values (NULL,0, 50),(1,51, 60),(4,61, 75), (16,76,100) 
        as I(weightRank,lowNumber, highNumber)

-- here we create a temp dynamic table to weight the marks 

        on 
            allmarks.marks between I.lowNumber AND I.HighNumber

group by id,name
```